# python `with open` doesn't create or update .log file

Tags: python, logging, discord.py

Trying out discord.py. Have set up a simple error that's supposed to appear in the log file. Here's the code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'raise-exception':
        raise discord.DiscordException


@client.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    with open('err.log', 'a+') as f:
        if event == 'on_message':
            log_entry = 'log entry'
            f.write(log_entry)
        else:
            raise
```

When an error is being triggered `err.log` file doesn't get updated. Nothing happens whatsoever.
If I add `print(log_entry)`, it prints out log entry in console (which only means that condition was met) but still doesn't do anything to the `err.log` file. I've also tried using .txt file instead, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: you're not specifying the full path so the file may be generated, but in an unexpected location.

Comment: You may have to call `f.flush()` to force the buffer to be written to the file

Comment: @monkut Absolute path works, thanks for advice. Although I'd like to keep it relative. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Where is you `err.log` file present ? Can you please specify the path in which err.log you are trying to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not specify any path while reading or writing a file, it takes the `current working directory (cwd)` as your base path.

In your case when you `open` the file with `a+` mode, it must be creating a file at your `cwd`.

CWD is the path from where you invoked your python script. You can check it from python by :

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

So if you do not provide any path and just write the file name, this is the path where your files will be written. If you want to use relative path you can do so after looking at your `cwd` and creating relative path string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to recommend `pathlib` it can make path handling easier.

With pathlib you can create the file relative to the source like this:

```
from pathlib import Path


SOURCE_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).parent


@client.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    errorlog_filepath = SOURCE_DIRECTORY / 'err.log'
    with errorlog_filepath.open('a+') as f:
        if event == 'on_message':
            log_entry = 'log entry'
            f.write(log_entry)
        else:
            raise
```

Comment: Thanks, that may be useful if there are multiple usage cases of open with